# Need help importing a quiz from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help on using a quiz from an external text file but with the following code below, it only prints "Correct" for the last question in the text file and all other questions are just said as "Incorrect" even when the correct answer is given. Detail[0] is the column with the question and detail[3] is the column with the correct answer. How do I proceed with this?

What's in the text file:

```
What is 1+1,1,2,2
What is 2+2,4,1,4
```

Code below:

```
def quiz():

    file = open("quiz.txt","r")
    for line in file:
       detail = line.split(",")
       print(detail[0])
       select = input("Select 1 or 2: ")
       if select == detail[3]:
          print("Correct")
       else:
          print("Incorrect")
quiz()
```

Comment: Please provide entire code, so that this kind of question is useful for anyone in future.

Comment: please show the sample data of your text file...

Comment: This is the full code, and the contents of my text file have been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## !/usr/bin/python3

def quiz():

```
file = open("quiz.txt","r")
for line in file:
    detail = line.split(",")
    print(detail[0])
    detail[3] = detail[3].strip('\n')
    select = input("Select 1 or 2: ")
    if select == (detail[3]):
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

quiz()

you had a \n at the end of the string and wasnt matching!

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to have sorted out the problem. Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Without a few lines of "quiz.txt" it's hard to be sure, but here's a guess:  Your input is a csv file with a carriage return separating lines, but the last line doesn't have a carriage return.

If you print detail (i.e. insert a 'print(detail)' you can quickly determine if this is the case.

edit:

After seeing your data, I recognize an additional problem:  you're comparing 'select' against the last element of 'detail'.  What you want to do is compare 'detail[select]' against 'detail[3]'.

I tested the following and it seems to do what you want:

```
file = open("quiz.txt","r")
for line in file:
    detail = line.split(",")
    select = input("Select 1 or 2: ")
    if detail[select] == detail[3].strip():
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

In the future when you are getting unexpected behavior, try printing the values you are comparing to see they are what you expect.  inserting  'print(detail)' and 'print(select)' statements would have made your problem immediately obvious.

Comment: It prints this out `['What is 1+1', '1', '2', '2\n']` for all three of the questions. I added another question to see if it would still only work for the last one, and it does only work for the last question

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I also got another answer but I will see which works better out of the two.

Answer (score 0):

The result of input is an int, while the result of line.splitis a string.
You're making that comparison: `'2'==2` which return False

Comment: So will I have to convert it to a str(variable)? Or how would I do this?

Comment: either int('2') == 2 or '2' == str(2)